# user form_alter to change text on button for user_pass form

Tags: 7

```
function footheme_form_alter($form, $form_state, $form_id) {
if($form_id == 'user_pass') {
 $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'reset password';
 print "boom";
 }
```

This does not work, "boom" is printing so I know it works but this is wrong

```
 $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'reset password';
```

here is the debug output

```
Array
(
    [#form_id] => user_pass
    [#type] => form
    [#build_id] => form-dadfsdfsd
    [#id] => user-pass
    [#method] => post
    [#action] => /user/password
    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
        (
            [0] => form
            [1] => block
        )

    [#tree] => 
    [#parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#validate] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_pass_validate
        )

    [#submit] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_pass_submit
        )

    [#theme] => Array
        (
            [0] => user_pass
        )

    [#processed] => 
    [#defaults_loaded] => 1
    [#required] => 
    [#attributes] => Array
        (
        )

    [#title_display] => before
    [#array_parents] => Array
        (
        )

    [#block] => stdClass Object
        (
            [bid] => 72
            [module] => system
            [delta] => main
            [theme] => footheme
            [status] => 1
            [weight] => -14
            [region] => content
            [custom] => 0
            [visibility] => 0
            [pages] => 
            [title] => 
            [cache] => -1
            [css_class] => 
            [subject] => 
            [last_in_region] => 1
        )

    [#weight] => 1
    [name] => Array
        (
            [#type] => textfield
            [#title] => E-mail
            [#size] => 60
            [#maxlength] => 254
            [#required] => 1
            [#default_value] => 
            [#description] => A password reset message will be sent to your e-mail address.
            [#input] => 1
            [#autocomplete_path] => 
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax_process_form
                )

            [#theme] => textfield
            [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_element
                )

            [#pre_render] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ctools_dependent_pre_render
                )

            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                )

            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => name
                )

            [#weight] => 0
            [#processed] => 1
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#id] => edit-name
            [#name] => name
            [#value] => 
            [#ajax_processed] => 
            [#sorted] => 1
            [#children] => 
  E-mail *




            [#printed] => 1
        )

    [form_build_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => form-CyR7yFGjBz2kf85j4mMIhozHP-_OPIk
            [#id] => form-CyR7yFGjBz2kf85j4mzD4aIhozHP-_OPIk
            [#name] => form_build_id
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_build_id
                )

            [#input] => 1
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax_process_form
                )

            [#theme] => hidden
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_build_id
                )

            [#weight] => 0.002
            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#ajax_processed] => 
            [#sorted] => 1
            [#children] => 

            [#printed] => 1
        )

    [form_id] => Array
        (
            [#type] => hidden
            [#value] => user_pass
            [#id] => edit-user-pass
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_id
                )

            [#input] => 1
            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => ajax_process_form
                )

            [#theme] => hidden
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_id
                )

            [#weight] => 0.003
            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#name] => form_id
            [#ajax_processed] => 
            [#sorted] => 1
            [#children] => 

            [#printed] => 1
        )

    [actions] => Array
        (
            [#type] => actions
            [submit] => Array
                (
                    [#type] => submit
                    [#value] => E-mail new password
                    [#input] => 1
                    [#name] => op
                    [#button_type] => submit
                    [#executes_submit_callback] => 1
                    [#limit_validation_errors] => 
                    [#process] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => ajax_process_form
                        )

                    [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => button
                        )

                    [#defaults_loaded] => 1
                    [#tree] => 
                    [#parents] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => submit
                        )

                    [#array_parents] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => actions
                            [1] => submit
                        )

                    [#weight] => 0
                    [#processed] => 1
                    [#required] => 
                    [#attributes] => Array
                        (
                        )

                    [#title_display] => before
                    [#id] => edit-submit
                    [#ajax_processed] => 
                    [#sorted] => 1
                    [#children] => 
                    [#printed] => 1
                )

            [#theme_wrappers] => Array
                (
                    [0] => container
                )

            [#process] => Array
                (
                    [0] => form_process_actions
                    [1] => form_process_container
                )

            [#weight] => 100
            [#defaults_loaded] => 1
            [#tree] => 
            [#parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => actions
                )

            [#array_parents] => Array
                (
                    [0] => actions
                )

            [#processed] => 1
            [#required] => 
            [#attributes] => Array
                (
                    [class] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => form-actions
                        )

                )

            [#title_display] => before
            [#id] => edit-actions
            [#sorted] => 1
            [#children] => 


            [#printed] => 1
        )

    [#sorted] => 1
    [#children] => 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having arguments as call by value you should have it by reference, so little change to your codes as

```
/**
* Implements hook_form_alter()
*/
function footheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_pass') {
   $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('reset password');
   print "boom";
 }
}
```

and then clear your caches.

Comment: cool thanks so much! This code worked before in Drupal 6, I think I remember reading that the pass by reference requirement changed in D7, is this the case?

Comment: not sure if it was required in drupal 6 but in the [syntax](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) it is pass by reference.