# Use form_alter to change description under reset password field for user_pass form

Tags: 7, theming, forms

I'd like to change the text below the reset password field. I took a look at this [answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/87281/user-form-alter-to-change-text-on-button-for-user-pass-form), and it talks about changing the button, but I need a bit of help to change the text.

Here is the debug output and it looks like I need to access #description

```
[name] => Array
  (
    [#type] => textfield
    [#title] => E-mail
    [#size] => 60
    [#maxlength] => 254
    [#required] => 1
    [#default_value] => 
    [#description] => A password reset message will be sent to your e-mail address.
    [#input] => 1
    [#autocomplete_path] => 
    [#process] => Array
      (
        [0] => ajax_process_form
      )
```

This is how I would change the button:

```
function footheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'user_pass') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t('reset password');
    print "boom";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

```
if ($form_id == 'user_pass') {
  $form['name']['#description'] = t('This is a test');
}
```